# Seeder for pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-seeding

I have pivot table taggable, it's table for Many To Many Polymorphic Relations (Tag and post) in Laravel:

```
taggable_id - id of Post
tag_id - id of Tag
taggable type - location of post model (default value"App/Models/Posts/Post")
is_search_term - boolen (0 or 1)
```

How create seeder which for post with id 1 (taggable_id) set 0 tag id.

For post with id 2 set tag id 1.

For post with id 3 set tag id 1 and id 2.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Check the namespace of the Model if it matches your convention or not .Since Your 'taggable type' attribute has default type, excluded it from seeding through faker.

```
$factory->define(App/Models/Posts/Post::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {

return [
    'taggable_id' => function(){
        return factory('App/Models/Posts/Post')->create()->id;
    },
    'tag_id' => function(){
        return factory('App/Models/Tags/Tag')->create()->id;
    },
    'is_search_term' => $faker->boolean
]; });
```

Comment: @Georg Could you please elaborate mate ?

Comment: I want that algorithm create fields like this:

Comment: taggable_id 1, tag_id 1
taggable_id 2, tag_id 1
taggable_id 2, tag_id 2
taggable_id 3, tag_id 1

Comment: Do you mean if you have taggable_id = n, then tag_id = m(m is any number) but count of entry in taggable table with the tag_id for the same taggable_id(taggable_id = n) should be less than n-1 ? Or is it if the taggable_id = n then faker should create multiple records having tag_id in the range of 1 to n-1 and taggable_id = n ?